# Saving search settings in a site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, site-template

I am trying to template a site so that a copy of it can be automatically created (using JSOM) on a button click at the parent site. This part works fine, however the site collection also has custom search settings, which should be cascaded from the root site.

These search settings do not seem to be included in the site template. The setting that is of particular importance is the search navigation (shown below) which should be set to inherit from the parent.

[image: Desired setting]

Does anyone know how to include these settings in a site template, or even if it is possible to do this? This is by far the preferable solution. However, failing that, does anyone know how to set a site to inherit search navigation links using JavaScript?

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: Hi Ryan,
Just wondering if you've ever found a solution for this. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry Maureen, we couldn't find a solution to this in the end. We ended up just hiding the search bar using a snippet of css on the template page to improve consistency - though this still doesn't affect the views of document libraries and the like.